# Why this simple connection code can't connect just to a certain website?

Tags: java, http, request

This code should return the source-view of a website.
My problem is with the site: https://www.fxp.co.il (a Hebrew forums site)

It returns the response code 403 with the message "Forbidden"; This is suepr weird because the site works well, also I added a User-Agent which is supposed to solve the 403 issue.

Am I doing anything wrong? Do you get the source-view for this website or the problem is in Java's Libraries?

.

```
private static final String MY_USER_AGENT; //taken from https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent

private static String getSourceView(URL url) throws IOException
{
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", MY_USER_AGENT);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));

        StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            responseBuilder.append(line);
        }

        return responseBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Please check the site in a new session or browser. There are some security measures taken that probably result in the experienced result when connecting from Java.

Comment: What do you mean in a new session? I now tried to use a different User-Agent, I changed it to the one I got in the Firefox website, and it still returns 403..

Comment: I think he means that you should open a Private Window in your browser, and try to load the URL there.  That will tell you whether you need the session cookie(s) which indicate a current login, in order to view that URL.